# Cleaner namespaces for microcontroller registers

Tags: c, microcontroller, code-cleanup

Working with a microcontroller, often you'll have to write and read from registers, to make the code more readable, you'd define the register address along with its bits. This is somewhat fine, but it quickly gets messy when you've got register names that are really similar to each other, as seen here for example

```
#define SYSAHBCLKCTRL (*(unsigned int*) 0x40048080)
#define TMR16B0TCR (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C004)
#define TMR16B0TC (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C008)
#define TMR16B0PR (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C00C)
#define TMR16B0MR0 (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C018) // Match register
#define ISER1 (*(unsigned int*) 0xE000E104) // Enable IRQ
#define TMR16B0MCR (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C014) // Match Control
#define TMR16B0IR (*(unsigned int*) 0x4000C000) // Interrupt Flag Register
```

At this level, it's still somewhat manageable, but it gets far worse when you start defining the associated flags of each register, for example this one register

```
#define I2C1CONSET (* (unsigned int *) 0x4005C000)
#define I2C1CONSET_EN 0x40
// bit 5, start condition
#define I2C1CONSET_STA 0x20
// bit 4, stop condition
#define I2C1CONSET_STO 0x10
// bit 2, acknowledge signal
#define I2C1CONSET_ACK 0x04
```

At this point, I would much rather use something like a namespace, so I can do something like this:

```
I2C1CONSET |= _I2C1CONSET.EN | _I2C1CONSET.STA; // set EN and STA bits on I2C1CONSET register
```

Are there any clean alternatives to how I'm working right now?

Comment: Is a dot really that much clearer/neater than an underscore?

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore in file scope is reserved.

Comment: @NPE Not cleaner per sé, it's less error-prone because under a namespace there are only so few options I can choose from. In global namespace, after a while there will be lots of options I can choose from, any decent editor however will only show me the options defined under a non-global namespace.

Comment: @Azeirah: But any decent IDE with autocomplete will only show you the relevant ones if your naming is consistent (i.e. typing `I2C1CONSET_` will only give autocomplete suggestions for those four flags).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're right. I'm looking for a solution to a problem, but I don't know what the problem is. I do get frustrated by these registers, but I'm not sure why. I'll try to find out what I'm really trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bitfield, eg

```
struct i2c1conset_flags
{
    unsigned     : 2;
    unsigned ack : 1;
    unsigned     : 1;
    unsigned sto : 1;
    unsigned sta : 1;
    unsigned en  : 1;
};

static volatile union {
    unsigned value;
    struct i2c1conset_flags flags;
} *const I2C1CONSET = (void *)0x4005C000;
```

This allows you to write

```
I2C1CONSET->value = 0;
I2C1CONSET->flags.sto = 1;
```

and assuming C99

```
#define I2C1CONSET_FLAGS(...) ((struct i2c1conset_flags){ __VA_ARGS__ })

I2C1CONSET->flags = I2C1CONSET_FLAGS(.ack = 1, .en = 1);
```

But does this actually help readability? You have to decide that one for yourself.

---

Now that I've played around some more, I think this approach actually can help readability. The following is the best I could come up with, and I believe it does look pretty nice:

```
#define I2C1CONSET (*(volatile unsigned *)0x4005C000)
struct I2C1CONSET_flags
{
    unsigned     : 2;
    unsigned ack : 1;
    unsigned     : 1;
    unsigned sto : 1;
    unsigned sta : 1;
    unsigned en  : 1;
    unsigned     : 25;
};

#define flags(REG) \
    (*(volatile struct REG ## _flags *)&REG)

#define mask(REG, ...) \
    (((union { unsigned value; struct REG ## _flags flags; }){ \
        .flags = { __VA_ARGS__ } \
    }).value)

flags(I2C1CONSET).sto = 1;
I2C1CONSET |= mask(I2C1CONSET, .ack = 1, .en = 1);
```